# where can i find the actual code for Java's Lib

Tags: java, windows, processing

Hello guys im looking to learn more about Java specifically where is the actual code located on my computer when we compile code like in my case PROCESSING IDE and export the compiled sketch I get an executable file/program and the code looks very different from the actual code i wrote  and altho i know why i dont know what those other libraries look like in code and i think me reading it will learn how to write better code and move out from Processing's ide into a much better ide.

```
import processing.core.*; 
import processing.data.*; 
import processing.event.*; 
import processing.opengl.*; 

import muthesius.net.*; 
import org.webbitserver.*; 
import guru.ttslib.*; //this particular one is for voice? how can i change 
this to use other speech??

import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
```

the libraries above were part of my exported sketch and i want to know where i can find these in my pc and actually dive in and go over how some of this functions were written.

thanks for your pointers.

Comment: refer this - http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/

Comment: @roottraveller thank you, pretty scary code in that page btw,

Comment: you asked for library code. welcome to the world of programming. :D

Comment: Yes I did and I'm thankful and dived right in along with Kevin's link but yours is more suited for what I needed thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Processing is open source. You can find its source code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/processing/processing).

Java's source is included with your JDK.

But really, Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general questions like this. Please try to do some more research, and try to ask a more specific question in the future. Good luck.

Comment: Kevin Worman Thanks for your help